# Offline MySQL installation (Using deb file and no internet connection)

Tags: server, dpkg, mysql

I downloaded MySQL's installation package and ran the following command after installing a fresh Ubuntu server.

```
dpkg -i mysql-5.5.28-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
```

It installed fine and then I tried starting up the server manually

```
/opt/mysql/server-5.5/bin/mysqld
```

And the following error came up

```
/opt/mysql/server-5.5/bin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I install that library in an offline way ? I have no means whatsoever to an internet connection from that server and I can't even relocate it to have internet connection temporarily !

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried executing `sudo apt-get install` without parameters?
dpkg just install the package but sometimes it allows you even on missing dependencies. This should give you an error and it will tell you the missing dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I install that library in an offline way ?

The same way as you did mysql ofcourse. [Find the package, put it on your system and install it](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libaio1) with `dpkg`. You probably also need  http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/multiarch-support

---

btw: MySQL changelog for 5.5.10 states:

> The libaio library, which has been used on Linux systems since MySQL 5.5.4, is now linked into mysqld dynamically rather than statically. If the library is not already on your Linux system, install it using the appropriate package manager for your distribution. The libaio-dev library is not sufficient; you must have the libaio library.

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of the "mutliarch" library ?

Comment: http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch @MuhammadGelbana acc. to the packages the libaio depends on it. You might already have it installed but you never know ;)